# iOS: Why touchesBegan has some delay in some specific area in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, delay, touchesbegan

I'm making a custom keyboard and I'm in a really weird situation.

I've noticed that when I catch the event touchesBegan at the rear left (about 20 pixels) of the UIView (inputView), I'll have some delay in here.
Any action I do in touchesBegan will be perform slower than other area.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
self.keypop.hidden = false
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
{
self.keypop.hidden = true
}
```

And this trouble affects my app's performance.
In this example, I will not see the keypop appears when I touched on the rear left because `self.keypop.hidden` was delayed in showing up.

I don't know why, or is this an error from iOS 9?
I've been stuck on this trouble for a week.

Answer (score 10):

In my situation I was using touchBegan in a CollectionView and it was delaying touches when I tap 
Its worked with me by simply added this code

In Swift,

```
self.collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false
/*delaysContentTouches applies to all UIScrollView instances.*/
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer here seems to have fixed the same issue in our keyboard:

[UISystemGateGestureRecognizer and delayed taps near bottom of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27188832/442896)

With the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let window = view.window!
    let gr0 = window.gestureRecognizers![0] as UIGestureRecognizer
    let gr1 = window.gestureRecognizers![1] as UIGestureRecognizer
    gr0.delaysTouchesBegan = false
    gr1.delaysTouchesBegan = false
}
```

Comment: This saved my life! I've been having this issue for a while now with a SpriteKit app where I sometimes need to do things at the top and bottom of the screen, but it always had weird behavior.

Comment: This works, but if you use gesture recognizers, instead, they seem to just work properly. For me (a SpriteKit game where I wanted touch-down to work), I used a long press with minimum duration set to 0, and triggered on state.began. Technique from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38143619/3937